# Could not obtain c# compiler error when using monodevelop

Tags: mono, c#

I dont know whether this is considered a programming question or not, so correct me if im wrong. How can i get mono develop to compile my c# projects?

At present it wont build, and i get an error saying 'could not obtain c# compiler, c# compiler not found for mono / .net 3.5' as i understand it, the c# compiler for mono is `dmcs`. Calling dmcs from terminal works fine. How can i get mono develop to build correctly?

Answer (score 13):

you can also install the compiler for the versions

```
sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs
```

Answer (score 3):

You can work around this by switching your project's runtime to .NET 4.0

Comment: Mine was set to 2.0, and I had only downloaded mcs (which compiles for 4.0. I changed properties, it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

You also can stay with the previous mono/.net (such as 2.0, 3.0) by installing the respective compiler. Go to the Ubuntu Software Center, and search for "C# compiler", you will find the earlier compiler there.